# How To Stop Git-Bash command on windows

Tags: android, git, bash, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing HTML 5 Android app using [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/).

it successfully builds and run successfully.

But after opening a application in my device `nexus 7`(works correctly in device),
the git bash on my laptop just doesn't let me enter new command. it just stays at `LAUNCH SUCCESS`.

My question is **how can i enter new command or run/build the app again?**, without exit and opening the git-bash again.

Here is screenshot of Git-bash command line.

[image: screenshot of Git-bash command line]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm not familiar with how Ionic works but should you be doing this in Git Bash? Did you try on [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), since you seem to be on windows?

Anyhow, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> should do, have you tried that?

Comment: thanks, `ctrl+c` worked, now it lets me to write new command , but the text is overlapped and i cant read it.   but then i run the `clear` command and everything works fine. thank you.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using the git cli directly, pressing `q` in the keyboard will also do the job for you.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is the most used task killing command for command based working windows.

Comment: When I run Jasmine tests on `git-bash` it ignores `ctrl+c`

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>end</kbd> is what worked for me

Answer (score 1):

`CTRL` + `C` normally works I used to have to restart CLI every time because it lagged or stopped responding. For Git Bash specifically, The `q` button works perfect to abort processes and continue with workflow

Answer (score 1):

I am using GitBash in windows and cntrl + c didn't work.

Instead this worked for me

> cntrl + end

and then press

> cntrl + x

to abort/interrupt.